# try catch question

Tags: c#, wcf, exception

Im doing this in c#. These are the code layers

VIEW -> VIEWHANDLER -> BusinessLayer -> WCF SERVICE

The view calls the ViewHandler which calls the business layer which calls the service. The service will throw some fault exception. All exceptions are handled in the View handler. The business layer re-throws the fault exception it got from the service as is to be handled in the VIEWHANDLER. What is the best way to rethrow it in the BusinessLayer?

```
catch(FaultException f)
{
throw f;
}
```

or

```
catch(FaultException f)
{
throw;
}
```

Does "throw f" resets the call stack information held in the caught exception? and does throw send it as-is?

Comment: Yes, and yes. If you do `throw f` then when the exception is ultimately caught and handled it will have the wrong stack trace attached.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `throw f;` will reset the stack.

`throw;` will not.

In either case, if this is all you are doing in the `catch` block, you are better off not using a `try-catch` block at all as it is pointless.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should use `throw` and not `throw f`. If you don't do anything in the `catch` statement you can leave out the `catch`.